# Display integer in UI

Tags: android, android-activity

How to display an integer `int a;` ( present in activity A1) in another activity A2.
And By display i mean, to print it in the UI when A2 is accessed.

Plz tell what to write in the java file and also in XML file.
ThnX in advance.

Comment: it is vary basic question plz google once and simply use intent fro this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Activity1 class

```
    int a=2;
    Intent act2=new Intent(this,Activity2.class);
        act2.putExtra("A",a);
        startActivity(act2);
```

In Activity2 class

```
    Intent i = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
    int a = extras.getInt("A");
    tv.setText(a);//considering textView id is tv..
```

Comment: thnx! now in XML file of Activity2, and in the textView id tv, do i have to write some special code for this??

Comment: In xml file ... <TextView android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"           android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

Answer (score 0):

activity A1

where you are pushing activity A2

```
intent.putExtra("keyName", "somevalue");
```

activity A2

onCreate function

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
if(extras !=null)
{
int value = extras.getInt("keyName");
}
```

Comment: got it, but now how to display this "keyname" in the UI?? Will i have to create a new textView?

Answer (score 0):

Better you can use the global variable for storing it by taking one class x extending the Application and put the variable getter setter declare that class in the Manifests file in the Application tag.So you can access there variables anywhere in the project like getters setters.